# How to accelerate the build of the workspace in squish?

Tags: squish

In Squish, I have a test suite with approximately 80 tests cases and 20 tests suite resources (.py file containing steps).

Unfortunately, at each save of change in a test case (or in suite resource), Squish re-build the workspace very slowly.

How to avoid the re-build or accelerate it ?

Comment: Please try with Squish 6.4.1. If the problem persists please contact the vendor to analyze the problem. There is no simple, general switch to flip that would resolve the problem.

Comment: Note : my version is Squish 6.2.0

Comment: There were changes regarding this area in more recent Squish versions. Some issues require updating. You can give it a try with 6.4.1, you can install any number of Squish packages at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This might help your question. Click on edit--> and Server settings, you should be able to get this information on the pop up window
Squish version used : 6.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Using eclipse photon with squish as plugin instead of Squish IDE in standalone resulted in an acceleration of about 25%.

https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/eclipse.ide.integration.html

Another factor in my case is the usage of wildcard imports in phyton scripts such as:

from Module import * -> which slows down the build process.